# How to write a function that separately groups an array with objects of different types?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

This question concerns the latest version of TypeScript, and so may be updated as newer versions come out.

Let's say I have the following set of types:

```
type A = {type: "A"; a_data : string};
type B = {type : "B"; b_data : string};
type C = {type : "C'; c_data : string};
```

And I define the following disjunction type:

```
type AnyABC = A | B | C;
```

My goal is to have a function, of the approximate form: (You can remove/add some parameters.)

```
function groupByKey(array : AnyABC[], key : (abc : AnyABC) => string)
```

That will accept an array of a mix of `A, B, C` objects and return an object or an ES6 `Map` with separate bins for `A[]`, `B[]`, and `C[]`. So you could go:

```
let a = result.A[0]
```

And `a` would be strongly typed as `A`.

**The actual code for doing this is just simple Javascript and less important. More important is how to encode the types correctly.**

Even if there are no `A`-type values in `AnyABC[]`, I still want the `A` bin to be an empty array `[]`. This means that the Javascript has to get some kind of object that contains a list of keys, so it can't all be eraseable type information.

I have my own attempt at the solution, which I'm going to add as an answer, but I'm looking for other, possibly better solutions too.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have thought this out, so I don't know if my answer is an improvement.  The best I can do is this:

```
function groupByKeys<T>(
  arr: T[keyof T][],
  selector: (item: T[keyof T]) => keyof T,
  possibleKeys: (keyof T)[],
): ArrayProps<T>;
function groupByKeys<T>(
  arr: T[keyof T][],
  selector: (item: T[keyof T]) => keyof T
): Partial<ArrayProps<T>>;
function groupByKeys<T>(
  arr: T[keyof T][],
  selector: (item: T[keyof T]) => keyof T,
  possibleKeys?: (keyof T)[],
): Partial<ArrayProps<T>> {
  const ret = {} as {[K in keyof T]: T[K][]};
  if (possibleKeys) {
    possibleKeys.forEach(k => ret[k] = []);
  }
  arr.forEach(i => {
    const k = selector(i);
    if (!(k in ret)) {
      ret[k] = [];
    }
    ret[k].push(i);
  })
  return ret;
}
```

So my `possibleKeys` parameter differs from yours in that it's an array, not an object.  Presumably `Object.keys(possibleKeys)` on yours results in mine.

```
type A = { type: 'A', a_data: string };
type B = { type: 'B', b_data: string };
type C = { type: 'C', c_data: string };
type AnyABC = A | B | C;
declare const arr: AnyABC[];
```

Here's how you call it:

```
type ABCHolder = { A: A, B: B, C: C };  
groupByKeys<ABCHolder>(arr, i => i.type);
```

or, if you absolutely care about the output having some empty arrays instead of possibly missing some keys:

```
groupByKeys<ABCHolder>(arr, i => i.type, ['A','B','C']);
```

So, this works about the same as yours, with some differences.  Upsides:

- No meaningless inputs; instead you specify the type parameter and it gets erased.  Or you pass in the type parameter and a list of keys (which is a bit redundant), but you're not passing in any nulls.
- Since you specify that type parameter it won't let you put in `'D'` in `possibleKeys`.
- You are also prevented from doing `x => "hello"`.

Downsides:

- It would be nice to not need the type parameter or indeed refer to anything like the type `{A:A, B:B, C:C}`, but such type inference is apparently a little much for the compiler.  (A possible refactor is to pass in the actual output object as a parameter, and it will copy results into it.  If you're willing to do that I might have a different implementation for you.)
- Even though `x => "hello"` is excluded, it still allows `x => 'A'`, which is bad because `x` might be of type `B` or `C`.  Ideally the selector function is of the generic type `<K extends keyof T>(item: T[K])=>K`, which expresses the exact constraint you want... but the compiler absolutely cannot witness that `x => x.type` matches that, and you are forced to assert it.  And since you can assert the same thing of `x => 'A'`, you are given no actual type safefy improvement.  So forget that.

So, that's what I have.  Hope it's helpful; good luck!

Comment: A great answer! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First, we define:

```
type KeySetFor<T> = {
    [key : string] : T;
}
```

This is a type that will encode the key names and what the resulting element type should be.

Then we define:

```
type KeyResultSetFor<T> = {
    [key in keyof T] : T[key][]
}
```

This is the result type and what our function returns.

Now comes the tricky part, the function definition:

```
function groupByKeys<T, TKeySet extends KeySetFor<T>>(array : T[], possibleKeys : TKeySet, selector : (k : T) => string) : KeyResultSetFor<TKeySet>
```

And you call the function like this:

```
let arr = [] as AnyABC[];
let x = Arr.groupByKeys(arr, {
    A : null as A,
    B : null as B,
    C : null as C
}, x => x.type);
```

This works, with the AutoComplete function of my IDE correctly displaying that `x` has the members `{A : A[], B : B[], C : C[]}` and the TypeScript compiled will correctly complain if I try to access `x.D` for example.

However, there are some issues:

1. The weird `null` values. You could actually replace them with any other value as long as it's cast to the type `A/B/C`. They're completely ignored. It's just very weird to see this in an API.
2. You can also put `D : null as C` in the keys object and it will work.
3. You can also put `x => "hello"` in the selector function and it will work, even though `type` is of the type `"A" | "B" | "C"`.